# A simpler proof that if $m\mid n$ then there is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Question 18.I.4 from Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* asks for a proof of the following, where $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are treated as rings:

> If $n$ is a multiple of $m$, then $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

After reading ahead to the next chapter on quotient rings, the method that suggests itself to me is to use cosets. Let $n = md$ and define $f: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ to send $a + n\mathbb{Z} \mapsto a + m\mathbb{Z}$. This is a well-defined map, because if $a + n\mathbb{Z} = b + n\mathbb{Z}$ then $a - b \in n\mathbb{Z} = md\mathbb{Z} \subset m\mathbb{Z}$, and so $a + m\mathbb{Z} = b + m\mathbb{Z}$. Then the homomorphism properties of $f$ are clear from the definitions of coset addition and multiplication.

However, this argument is really about the rings $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, and since the book hasn't defined quotient rings or given the homomorphism theorems up to this point I suspect that a proof using more basic concepts is called for. In fact, the book has not given a formal definition of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ as a ring, so I am not sure how to prove things about it in general.  Should its elements be thought of as equivalence classes of integers, or as the integers $\{0, 1, ... m-1\}$ with addition and multiplication defined by taking remainders modulo $m$?

So I have two questions:

1. Is the argument above actually a proof of this statement?
2. Is there a better proof using only the more basic properties of modulo arithmetic?

Comment: Without a formal definition of $\mathbb Z_n$, it is hard to give a formal proof about $\mathbb Z_n$ :)

Comment: There is a more general and abstract proof not using properties specific to modular arithmetic: if $I\triangleleft J\triangleleft R$ are ideals of a ring $R$ then there are quotient maps $R\to R/I\to R/J$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ha, point taken.  I still wonder what kind of answer the author expects the student to be able to give at this point, but I guess I will be content to treat $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ as the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and not worry further about it. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The argument is OK with the caveat that I hope you have a concrete explanation with the part where you say "*are clear*." You were probably just saving space, but as you know some students often jump the gun on what is clear :)
2. Both of the "ways of thinking about" the elements of $\Bbb Z_m$ are valid since really they are the same thing. That is, $n$ is equivalent to $k$ if and only if $n-k\in m\Bbb Z$, if and only if $n+m\Bbb Z=k+m\Bbb Z$ as cosets. So, each equivalence class corresponds to one and only one coset.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Yes, I have often guilty of jumping the gun in this respect, but in this case I really have the details in mind. ;-)  It seems to me that the coset notation makes it easier to distinguish integers, residue classes $\pmod{n}$ and residue classes $\pmod{m}$, but I think I can see now how to rephrase the argument in terms of residue classes if I had to.